How to enable csr on a SvelteKit component?
I'm aware that I can enable/disable csr on SvelteKit routes, but can I do it on a single component?
My current code looks like this:
layout.ts:
export const prerender = true;
export const ssr = true;

page.svelte:
<script lang="ts">
  import MyComponent from '$lib/components/MyComponent.svelte'
<script>

something to be rendered on the server

<MyComponent /> <!-- To be rendered on the client -->

I've tried this on MyComponent.svelte but it didn't work
<script lang="ts">
  export const csr = true;
</script>
....


There is no component-level setting.
There is a SvelteKit specific browser flag you could use:
import { browser } from '$app/environment';

{#if browser}
    <Component />
{/if}

You could also wrap the component in #await, though this is a bit of a hack:
{#await Promise.resolve() then _}
    <Component />
{/await}

